# How to force single inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
public class A
{
}

public sealed class B : A
{
}
```

And I want that only my `B` class (defined in the same assembly of `A`) can inherits `A`.
How can I do?

Answer (score 5):

> And I want that only my B class (defined in the same assembly of A) can inherits A. How can I do?

There is simply no need for inheritance then..

```
public sealed class B
{
  //includes all methods of A and B
}
```

Comment: Have I to duplicate my code? This is not a good thing... Class A must exsist.

Comment: How would it be duplication? Only one class can inherit it so it's a 1-1 mapping between the base class and the inheritor. Duplication is impossible with that.

Comment: You might want to explain why `A` can't be a part of B.

Comment: I have my class A (and its methods), I have my class B (and its methods), where to take A methods for class B? See the access modifier, I want to have the possibility to use A and B from another assembly.

Comment: He probably means he only wants class a to be inheritable from within the same assembly and not only by class b in the same assembly. If that's the case than his question is not accurate ;)

Comment: @Nick: ehh?  `where to take A methods for class B? See the access modifier` That makes no sense. Please elaborate

Comment: @jgauffin Please show me a more concrete example (classes with at lead one method).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `internal` constructor, this prevents other assemblies from using your class.

```
public class A 
{
    internal A() { }    
}
public sealed class B : A { }
```

And, if you don't care about performance:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Type c = GetType();
        if (c != typeof(A) && c != typeof(B)) throw ....;
    }
}
```

Comment: Other assemblies can use class A (see the public access modifier).

Comment: @Nick They can use it, but not inherit from it. And you don't say "use" you only said "inherit".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use composition instead of inheritance to restrict the visibility of base type members.

Answer (score 0):

If only B can inherit A, then do you really need inheritance in the first place?

If it's to split a class that became too big, you're not following good practice as it is not likely to have a single responsibility.

Now if for some awkward reason you actually do need this, you can try that:

```
public class B
{
    private sealed class A : B
    {

    }
}
```

And tweak it to your needs.